# Problemas con el paquete "pyearth"

Tags: python

Al importar el paquete `pyearth` presenta error.

Lo que ejecuto:

```
import numpy as np
import warnings
from pyearth import Earth
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score, mean_squared_error
```

Y el error que aparece al ejecutar el código anterior:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-9efc85acdf4a> in <module>
      1 import numpy as np
      2 import warnings
----> 3 from pyearth import Earth
      4 from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
      5 from sklearn.metrics import r2_score, mean_squared_error

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyearth\__init__.py in <module>
      4 @author: jasonrudy
      5 '''
----> 6 from .earth import Earth
      7 
      8 from ._version import get_versions

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyearth\earth.py in <module>
----> 1 from ._forward import ForwardPasser
      2 from ._pruning import PruningPasser, FEAT_IMP_CRITERIA
      3 from ._util import ascii_table, apply_weights_2d, gcv
      4 from ._types import BOOL
      5 from sklearn.base import RegressorMixin, BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyearth\_basis.pxd in init pyearth._forward()

pyearth\_basis.pyx in init pyearth._basis()

pyearth\_types.pyx in init pyearth._types()

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py in __getattr__(attr)
    303 
    304         if attr in __former_attrs__:
--> 305             raise AttributeError(__former_attrs__[attr])
    306 
    307         # Importing Tester requires importing all of UnitTest which is not a

AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'int'.
`np.int` was a deprecated alias for the builtin `int`. To avoid this error in existing code, use `int` by itself. Doing this will not modify any behavior and is safe. When replacing `np.int`, you may wish to use e.g. `np.int64` or `np.int32` to specify the precision. If you wish to review your current use, check the release note link for additional information.
The aliases was originally deprecated in NumPy 1.20; for more details and guidance see the original release note at:
    https://numpy.org/devdocs/release/1.20.0-notes.html#deprecations
```

Necesito ayuda para arreglarlo, gracias!!

Comment: Ese [módulo](https://github.com/scikit-learn-contrib/py-earth) no se mueve hace seis años. Es muy posible que debas usar versiones mucho más viejas de numpy, scipy y scikit-learn. No es claro siquiera que eso deba funcionar bien con Python3, por ejemplo...

Comment: Es posiblemente por [incompatibilidades](https://github.com/scikit-learn-contrib/py-earth/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aclosed) entre pyearth, python y sus dependencias, ya que el desarrollo del módulo se ha detenido hace mucho tiempo. Es posible que funcione instalando versiones muy específicas de Python y sus dependencias.